# Dielectric sphere placed in another dielectric medium with uniform external field: is there a surface charge density?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, boundary-conditions, dielectric

Consider a dielectric sphere placed within a dielctric medium. There is a uniform electric field $E_0$ present throughout in the medium.

Would there be surface charge on the sphere?

Comment: is the considered field is mantaines uniform throughout even after the insertion of dielectric sphere ?

Comment: yes the field is constant outside the sphere

Comment: that is impossible

Comment: Here's the full question:

A dielectric sphere of radius a and relative permittivity $\epsilon_I$ is placed within a
dielectric medium of relative permittivity $\epsilon_E$, extending to inﬁnity in which a uniform
electric ﬁeld $E_0$ is present. Find the resulting electrostatic potentials inside and outside
the dielectric sphere.

Comment: I need to know whether there would be a surface charge on the sphere or not, as that determines the boundary conditions

Comment: Use more tags. It will increase probability of answering.

Comment: The field $E_0$ most probably refers to the field in the dielectric medium *before* the sphere is put in there. The sphere will change the total field outside - it will no longer be uniform.

Comment: Here is a [link to a pdf](http://www.df.unipi.it/~macchi/TEACHING/FISICA2/PROBLEMS/dielecsphereextfield.pdf) I found by googling.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there will be a surface charge density on the sphere. Because, the field in the outer medium will polarize the molecules of the dielectric and thus, there will come some surface charge density on the sphere. Notice that the dielectric sphere would still remain electrically neutral as a whole. The electric density will appear because of the redistribution of the electric charge.

Comment: But it would be weird to have a $\sigma$ in your final answer when it is not given in the question..